# Moved html file not @font-face not working

Tags: html, css, directory, font-face

I moved my html file "index.html" to my html folder named 'html' and now my css rules importing font-face are not working except for one. I have three one is directly from google api while the other two are on my computer. before i moved my html file they were all working fine. I have tried several suggestions form people I know marking it "!important," or even changing quotations and capitalization. I have made sure that each file's foont-family is directl the same name as the file and yet nothing unless i remove the the html file from the folder to its original position.

Please help. I would really appreciate it.

```
@font-face { 
    font-family: still time; 
    src: url ('../fonts/still time.ttf'); 
} 

@font-face { 
    font-family: "The Next Font" !important; 
    src: url('www.dafont.com/the-next-font.font');
 } 

@font-face { 
     font-family: "Vintage Avalanche" !important; 
     src: url('../fonts/Vintage Avalanche.otf');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `../` signifies the fonts are trying to be loaded from the folder one level up from the folder where the file resides. Initially, you used one `../`, meaning the `fonts` folder and the folder your `index.html` file were in were siblings:

```
root/fonts/[YOUR FONTS]
root/[SIBLING]/index.html
```

`../fonts/` attempts to navigate out of the folder that `index.html` is in, and then into the `fonts` folder, where in finds the fonts. Now that you have a secondary `html` folder, Your HTML file is now one level deeper:

```
[ROOT]/fonts/[YOUR FONTS]
[ROOT]/[SIBLING]/html/index.html
```

So in order to reference the fonts, you need to move up **two** levels rather than one in order to find the `fonts` folder, by adding an extra `../` in order to move a directory higher:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: still time;
    src: url ('../../fonts/still time.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "The Next Font" !important;
    src: url('www.dafont.com/the-next-font.font');
}
@font-face {
        font-family: "Vintage Avalanche" !important;
    src: url('../../fonts/Vintage Avalanche.otf');
}
```

The `www.dafont.com` font worked, because you provided an **absolute** URL, rather than a  **relative** one. Also, note that the font-face is relative to the CSS, so if you use an external CSS file, they will be relative to the CSS file, not the HTML file!

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, you have your CSS in an external CSS file, using the following structure:

```
practice/fonts/[YOUR FONTS]
practice/css/style.css
practice/html/index.html
```

As I mentioned with the relative paths, the fonts are loaded relative to the CSS. `practice/css/style.css` correlates to `http://[SITE]/practice/css/style.css`. Your fonts are at `http://[SITE]/practice/fonts/[FONT.EXT]`, so you need to go one level up:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: still time;
    src: url ('../fonts/still time.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "The Next Font" !important;
    src: url('www.dafont.com/the-next-font.font');
}
@font-face {
        font-family: "Vintage Avalanche" !important;
    src: url('../fonts/Vintage Avalanche.otf');
}
```

If anything, your fonts shouldn't have worked **before**. Considering they **did** work, you might be able to reference the fonts by removing the leading `../`:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: still time;
    src: url ('fonts/still time.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "The Next Font" !important;
    src: url('www.dafont.com/the-next-font.font');
}
@font-face {
        font-family: "Vintage Avalanche" !important;
    src: url('fonts/Vintage Avalanche.otf');
}
```

Alternatively, to ensure they work no matter **where** your CSS / HTML files are located, you could reference them **relative to the root** as such:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: still time;
    src: url ('/fonts/still time.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "The Next Font" !important;
    src: url('www.dafont.com/the-next-font.font');
}
@font-face {
        font-family: "Vintage Avalanche" !important;
    src: url('/fonts/Vintage Avalanche.otf');
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I am trying it right now but i didn't move the fonts the fonts are in its own folder not with the html

here is is a screenshot of the folder layout
[screen](https://gyazo.com/61b464ff2f4d06336b21f1f4195d0de6).

Comment: Ahh, that explains it. The font-face is relative to the CSS, not the HTML. What you're **now** looking for is **no** `../`. I'll update my answer to cover this.

Comment: Updated my answer to cover your comment; this should now fix the problem.

Comment: would the site be the html name

Comment: also i changed it to https:///index.html/practice/... nothing happened 
then i changed it to 'fonts/[font] nothing happened 
then /fonts/[font] nothing happened

Comment: How are you hosting this? Through localhost? How are you referencing the CSS file? `<link href="../css/style.css"?`Check to see if **any** of the CSS properties are being displayed. Have you confirmed you got the filenames correct? There's absolutely no reason why the above should not work... In fact, the only other option for relative reference is `folder-relative`, which would be `./fonts/[yourfont]`.

Comment: All filenames are correct every other css element is working only ones not working are vintage avalanche font and the next font, font it is local host this is just practice right now i am linking my css file by                              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "../css/style.css">
and everything else works but those fonts yet the Oswald font works since it is from google i have not changed the folder pathing for css to try to see if that works

Answer (score 0):

Since you moved your html to a different file location, it cannot access the right file anymore.

1. Change the link/path you are using to access files.

   - if you put the html inside a folder, try using "../" at the beginning of the path/link to signify that *you want to go up, one folder from where you are right now.*

Comment: May I see the folder hierarchy of the css file, html file and the font.

Comment: And one more thing, how do you call your css file?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/61b464ff2f4d06336b21f1f4195d0de6
that is the layout of folders and i call my css style style.css since its just practice

Comment: Hmm you call it as "style.css", not "../css/style.css"?

Comment: uh? yea its in the css folder so technichally it would ../css/style.css